# how to extract geographic latitude and longitude from the variable Store Location

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
if (!file.exists("ames-liquor.rds")) {
  url <- "https://github.com/ds202-at-ISU/materials/blob/master/03_tidyverse/data/ames-liquor.rds?raw=TRUE"
  download.file(url, "ames-liquor.rds", mode="wb")
}
data <- readRDS("ames-liquor.rds")
```

how to extract geographic latitude and longitude from the variable Store Location and check variable types?
and how to use the package lubridate to convert the Date variable to a date. Then extract year, month and day from the variable Date

I am having hard time figuring out how can I extract geographic latitude

I used the code below to pload data on R

Comment: I only read this question and the comment above after answering to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74298654/how-to-summarize-number-of-sales-volume-of-liquor-sold-and-amount-of-money-spen/) by the same [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20216460/user20216460). I have flagged the comment and deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `tidyr::extract` to extract the longitude and latitude. For the dates convert to a proper date using e.g. `as.Date`. Afterwards you could get the year, month and day using the respective functions from `lubridate`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

data |> 
  tidyr::extract(`Store Location`, into = c("lon", "lat"), 
                 regex = "\\((\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+) (\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)", 
                 remove = FALSE,
                 convert = TRUE) |> 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), 
         year = lubridate::year(Date), 
         month = lubridate::month(Date), 
         day = lubridate::day(Date)) |> 
  select(`Store Location`, lon, lat, Date, year, month, day)
#> # A tibble: 661,945 × 7
#>    `Store Location`                       lon   lat Date        year month   day
#>    <chr>                                <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 POINT (-93.619455 42.022848)         -93.6  42.0 2020-11-02  2020    11     2
#>  2 POINT (-93.669896 42.02160500000001) -93.7  42.0 2020-07-01  2020     7     1
#>  3 POINT (-93.669896 42.02160500000001) -93.7  42.0 2019-07-31  2019     7    31
#>  4 <NA>                                  NA    NA   2019-07-25  2019     7    25
#>  5 <NA>                                  NA    NA   2019-07-05  2019     7     5
#>  6 POINT (-93.618911 42.022854)         -93.6  42.0 2020-07-02  2020     7     2
#>  7 POINT (-93.669896 42.02160500000001) -93.7  42.0 2021-03-03  2021     3     3
#>  8 POINT (-93.619455 42.022848)         -93.6  42.0 2021-03-03  2021     3     3
#>  9 POINT (-93.669896 42.02160500000001) -93.7  42.0 2019-07-17  2019     7    17
#> 10 <NA>                                  NA    NA   2022-08-03  2022     8     3
#> # … with 661,935 more rows
```