# How to summarize number of sales, volume of liquor sold and amount of money spent in this R question

Tags: r, r-markdown

I used the following code to upload my data on R

```
if (!file.exists("ames-liquor.rds")) {
  url <- "https://github.com/ds202-at-ISU/materials/blob/master/03_tidyverse/data/ames-liquor.rds?raw=TRUE"
  download.file(url, "ames-liquor.rds", mode="wb")
}
data <- readRDS("ames-liquor.rds")
```

Then use this code to extract geographic latitude and longitude

```
data <- data %>% 
  separate(remove= FALSE,
           col = 'Store Location' , sep=" ",
           into=c("toss-it", "Latitude", "Longitude"))
data <- data %>% mutate(
  Latitude = parse_number(Latitude),
  Longitude = parse_number(Longitude)
)
```

Now I needed to

- Find the daily liquor sales in Ames in 2021: summarize number of sales, volume of liquor sold and amount of money spent.

But Im so confused how I need to do this part

Also I did use dput(head(data)) and got this result
structure(list(`Invoice/Item Number` = c("INV-31574300001", "INV-28409200221",
"INV-20965600005", "INV-20840300018", "INV-20413100006", "INV-28435900006"
), Date = c("11/02/2020", "07/01/2020", "07/31/2019", "07/25/2019",
"07/05/2019", "07/02/2020"), `Store Number` = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "Store Number", class = "factor"),
`Store Name` = c("Hy-Vee  #2 / Ames", "Hy-Vee Food Store #1 / Ames",
"Hy-Vee Food Store #1 / Ames", "Kum & Go #1215 / Ames", "Kum & Go #1215 / Ames",
"Cyclone Liquors"), Address = c("640 Lincolnway", "3800 W Lincoln Way",
"3800 W Lincoln Way", "4506 Lincoln Way", "4506 Lincoln Way",
"626 Lincoln Way"), City = c("Ames", "Ames", "Ames", "Ames",
"Ames", "Ames"), `Zip Code` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L), levels = "Zip Code", class = "factor"), `County Number` = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "County Number", class = "factor"),
County = c("STORY", "STORY", "STORY", "STORY", "STORY", "STORY"
), Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "Category", class = "factor"),
`Category Name` = c("Cocktails /RTD", "Mixto Tequila", "Canadian Whiskies",
"Canadian Whiskies", "Canadian Whiskies", "Imported Vodkas"
), `Vendor Number` = c("626", "395", "260", "260", "260",
"260"), `Vendor Name` = c("JDSO INC / Red Boot Distillery",
"PROXIMO", "DIAGEO AMERICAS", "DIAGEO AMERICAS", "DIAGEO AMERICAS",
"DIAGEO AMERICAS"), `Item Number` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "Item Number", class = "factor"), `Item Description` = c("Oxtails Rum Punch",
"Jose Cuervo Especial Silver", "Crown Royal Regal Apple Mini",
"Crown Royal Regal Apple", "Crown Royal Regal Apple", "Ketel One"
), Pack = c(6, 6, 10, 24, 24, 6), `Bottle Volume (ml)` = c(1750,
1750, 300, 375, 375, 1750), `State Bottle Cost` = c(5.97,
21, 7.35, 8, 8, 22), `State Bottle Retail` = c(8.96, 31.5,
11.03, 12, 12, 33), `Bottles Sold` = c(6, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6),
`Sale (Dollars)` = c(53.76, 63, 66.18, 48, 48, 198), `Volume Sold (Liters)` = c(10.5,
3.5, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 10.5), `Volume Sold (Gallons)` = c(2.77,
0.92, 0.47, 0.39, 0.39, 2.77), `Store Location` = c("POINT (-93.619455 42.022848)",
"POINT (-93.669896 42.02160500000001)", "POINT (-93.669896 42.02160500000001)",
NA, NA, "POINT (-93.618911 42.022854)"), `toss-it` = c("POINT",
"POINT", "POINT", NA, NA, "POINT"), Latitude = c(-93.619455,
-93.669896, -93.669896, NA, NA, -93.618911), Longitude = c(42.022848,
42.021605, 42.021605, NA, NA, 42.022854)), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange!  After your import and preparation steps, can you do `dput(head(data))` and paste the results into your question - this gives us an idea of what you are working with.    Is Ames a location designated in your table, or do you need to work it out from the lat/long of the stores?

Comment: I did edit my questin and that's correct names is the location